# iOS: How to access values from UITextField which is in custom cell of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a table view with custom cells which contains multiple text fields. I want to get values entered in text fields on a button click on somewhere in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is it possible ?

[image: Below is the screenshot of text fields which are in table view cell]

Above image is the screenshot of text fields which are in table view cell.

Comment: How many textfield do you have?

Comment: for visible cells only?

Comment: Add outlet and what you need for textfield in cell. Than you can add special tag for each textfield and cell, and implement delegate for textfield, where you can use **switch (textField.tag)** and handle each case by special tag of textField. Don't forget **cell.textField.delegate = self**

Comment: You can use of tag for each cells. When you want to access value of UITextField at that time get index value from CGPoint.

Comment: Is the button to save a set of changes made throughout the table? And the table can be scrolled so unsaved changes might go off the screen?

Comment: @Wain: Exactly thats what I needed. I have to save changes made throughout the table.

Answer (score 5):

you can get `UITextField` with help of `Tag` Functionality.

Suppose you have 3 `UITextField` in 1 `Cell`.

give `Tag` to `UITextField` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method in following way.

```
[cell.TextField1 setTag:(1000 + indexPath.row)];
[cell.TextField2 setTag:(5000 + indexPath.row)];
[cell.TextField3 setTag:(9000 + indexPath.row)];
```

for get `UITextField` you can use following line.

```
// Replace 1000 with your tag value
UITextField * textField = (UITextField *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:1000];
NSLog(@"Value of textfield = %@",[textField text]);
```

Comment: @ Abhishek : how to access value or string from [self.tableView viewWithTag:1000]; ?

Comment: @Ash please see the `updated answer`. I have used `NSlog` to print value of `UITextField`. you can take directly in `NSString Variable`.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to do so is to *define a custom cell* and make `Outlets` and `Properties` for your each textfields. Later from view controller get the cell and access the element from custom cell.

e.g.,

**Custom Cell:**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField1;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField2;

@end
```

**ViewController**

```
-(IBAction)btnGetText_Click:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger requiredVisibleCell = <<indexOfYourRequiredCellHere>>;
    CustomCell *cell = [[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:requiredVisibleCell];

    // Here is the text of your field
    NSString text = cell.txtField1;
}
```

**Note:** I assume you work for the visible cells only.

For the case other than this, you have to update your datasource(UITableView datasource NSDictionary, NSArray, Custom Object Collection etc) (using delegates, protocols) whenever your `UITextField` ends edit.

Then your button code will look like this:
(Assuming your data source is an array object some class `CustomObject` and has a property `yourRequireddata` which keeps data of `txtField1`).

```
-(IBAction)btnGetText_Click:(id)sender
{
    // Here is the text of your field
    CustomObject *obj = [dataSource objectAtIndex:0]; // Pass your required index

    // Here is the text of your field
    NSString *text = obj.yourRequireddata;
}
```

Hope it helps!